# JsonResult from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We're having some discussion in our team that all the methods which are returning JsonResult should be moved to WebApi 'controllers' so that there is a clean segregation.

I'm not too sure about that. Is it wrong for a MVC controller to return ActionResults as well as JsonResults?

Comment: `Is it wrong for a MVC controller to return ActionResults as well as JsonResults?` given that `JsonResult` inherits from `ActionResult` I can't see why you could think that it was 'wrong'?

Comment: Rory, I didn't think it was wrong but one of my teammates definitely thinks that it is wrong so I wanted to know if I was correct or not.

Comment: IMO, no it isn't at all. Although there's no reason you couldn't use shimron's approach and separate the Actions by their return types into separate controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our projects, we indeed move the actions for ajax request to a partial controller called "ScriptController" or "WebApiControler". 
I think it is good to maintain, codes also seem to clear.